# How to check data type of every single element of a vector in r?

Tags: r

I want to check if all elements are numeric in the vector y

`y <- c(8.2, 2.5, 4.3, 3.2, 4.9, 7.0, NA, 5.3, 7.7, NA, 8.1, 3.0, 6.4, 6.5)`
`is.numeric(y)`

is.numeric(y) gives me TRUE although there are NAs in the vector.
Is there a way to get the data type of every single element?

Comment: Use `str(y)` to see the structure/type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atomic vectors can only have a single data type. So if `is.numeric(your_vector)` is `TRUE`, then all elements of the vector are numeric.

There are different types of `NA`, e.g., `NA_character_` which is `character` class, `NA_real_` which is `numeric` class, etc. See the `?NA` help page for more detail. But since all elements of a vector must be the same class, you don't have to check the type of `NA` values in a numeric vector, you know they are numeric.

A `list` is a special kind of vector that can hold different classes.

You can test for any `NA` values in the vector with `anyNA()`. Or use `is.na()` to test each individual element.